# How does one prove that $\int_0^4xe^{(x-2)^4}dx=2k$ if $\int_0^4e^{(x-2)^4}dx=k$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, definite-integrals

> Suppose $\int_0^4e^{(x-2)^4}dx=k$. Prove that $\int_0^4xe^{(x-2)^4}dx=2k$.

I got stuck doing by parts:

$$  u=x \ \ \ \ dv=e^{(x-2)^4}dx $$
$$  du=dx \ \ \ \ \ \ \ v=? $$

What can be $v$. I can't say $v=k$, can I?

Comment: What substitution did you try and how did you do integration by parts?

Comment: OP, I had overlooked that the second integral for the suggestion by parts I made yesterday was supposed to be the iterated integral $$\int\int f(x)\mathrm dx \mathrm dx,$$ where $f(x)$ is the exponential function above. Instead I had wrongly written only a single integral. Thus, the question isn't as trivial as I'd thought. I'm sorry. I've therefore updated my suggestion, but it's not fully rigorous, thus I'll up vote this question, so someone with either better ideas, or who can make my argument rigorous, may do so. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A substitution $x = t +2$ yields:

$$\begin{align*}\int_0^4 x \exp((x-2)^4) \, dx &= \int_{-2}^2 (t + 2) \exp(t^4) \, dt = \color{red}{\int_{-2}^2 t \exp(t^4) \, dt} + 2\int_{-2}^2 \exp(t^4) \, dt \\
&= 2 \int_0^4 \exp((x - 2)^4) \, dx\end{align*}$$

Herein, the red integral vanishes as the function is symmetric around the origin.

Comment: Oh, beautiful! I don't know why I didn't consider that obvious change of variable; I probably hadn't thought it would help much, but see what it's done now! :D

Comment: That's sharp indeed.

Answer (score 2):

By the mean value theorem for integrals, it follows that there is a point $x_0$ in the interval $(0,4)$ so that $$\int_0^4xe^{(x-2)^4}\mathrm dx=x_0\int_0^4e^{(x-2)^4}\mathrm dx=kx_0.$$

It then remains to show that $x_0=2.$ I have not been able to see how to do this more rigorously, but a heuristic argument for why this must be so is as follows: You may view the calculations above as trying to determine the $x$-coordinate $x_0$ of the centre of gravity of the region defined by the equations $y=0,\,y=e^{(x-2)^4},\,x=0,\,x=4,$ so that the first integral above is the moment of inertia of the region about the $y$-axis. Then since the region is symmetric about the line $x=2,$ it follows that the $x$-coordinate of the centre of gravity, $x_0,$ must be equal to $2.$